# Paypal direct debit mandat / authorization possible?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm currently searching for a way to create an direct debit authorization to receive money from a paypal user after x days.

Ofcourse i already looked up https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/ , However I have a lot of problems with understanding the different terms on the paypal page.

I want a customer to press "buy" as usual ( -> login, auth, accept... ). But the money should not be transfered directly. I want to be able to hold this authorization until a specific event occurs. Only after that event the transfer should happen.

Can someone please tell me the correct term for this or maybe a how-to guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several features that could be useful depending upon the specifics of your use case. But if you just want to wait for an event, and that event should normally happen within a few days, the simplest answer is to request an authorization, and to request the funds capture when the event has occurred.

Comment: So I will basically just set the intent to authorize?